# Dúvida com Script para Gera Backup do banco de dados Sql Server 2014

Tags: sql-server

Estou fazendo desta forma:

```html
USE CEP_2014_09;
GO
BACKUP DATABASE CEP_2014_09
TO DISK = 'C:\Backup_teste\CEP_2014_09.bak'
   WITH FORMAT,
      MEDIANAME = 'z_CEP_2014_09',
      NAME = 'Full Backup of CEP_2014_09';
GO
```

```html
Mensagem 3201, Nível 16, Estado 1, Linha 1
Cannot open backup device 'C:\Backup_teste\CEP_2014_09.bak'. Operating system error 3(The system cannot find the path specified.).
Mensagem 3013, Nível 16, Estado 1, Linha 1
BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally.
```

Comment: Essa pasta existe: C:\Backup_teste\?

Comment: Sim, ele existe,

Comment: Verifique se não é problema de permissão usando outro endereço para a gravação. Exemplo TO DISK = 'C:\Users\<seu_usuario>\CEP_2014_09.bak'.

Comment: Vou perguntar de novo porque não ficou claro se essa pasta existe no servidor ou na sua maquina. Se esse banco esta no servidor essa pasta tem de existir no servidor. Essa pasta existe no servidor?

Comment: a pasta não existe no servidor! por isso o erro, vou fazer a criação

Answer (score 0):

Existem dois fatores que podem gera esse erro.

1. A pasta **Backup_teste**, não existe no mesmo local do servidor onde esta sendo executado a query.
2. O usuário que esta executando a query não tem permissão para (alterar/criar) a pasta **Backup_teste**.

Solução; verifique se a pasta existe e caso exista verifique se o usuário do sql tem permissão para altera-la.